# How to click on multiple checkboxes in selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to check multiple Checkbox in a table via reading data from `Excel`, it is actually able to read data from excel and locate the Checkbox but it does not check/click the checkbox. The ongoingPrecuationsChk.click(); is not working and it does not show any exception(skips execution of the line), can somebody explain to me why it's not checking/clicking the checkbox? Below is my html code:

```
<table id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl04_cbl_CCPOP01_01">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td>
    <input id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl04_cbl_CCPOP01_01_0"
 type="checkbox"
     name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl04$cbl_CCPOP01_01$0" 
value=" Universal    ">
<label for="ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl04_cbl_CCPOP01_01_0"> Universal   </label></td>
<td><input id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl04_cbl_CCPOP01_01_1" 
type="checkbox" 
name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl04$cbl_CCPOP01_01$1"
 value=" Aspiration  ">
<label for="ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl04_cbl_CCPOP01_01_1"> Aspiration  </label></td>
    <td><input id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl04_cbl_CCPOP01_01_2" 
type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl04$cbl_CCPOP01_01$2" 
value=" Respiratory ">
<label for="ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl04_cbl_CCPOP01_01_2"> Respiratory </label></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
```

I have tried the following code:

```
String valueOngoingPrecuations = data.getOngoingPrecuations().get(rowCnt);//data reading from excel(Aspiration,Universal)
            List<WebElement> ongoingPrecuations = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@type='checkbox']"));
            List<String> ongoingPrecuationsList = new ArrayList<String>(
                    Arrays.asList(valueOngoingPrecuations.split(",")));
            for (String ongoingPrecuationsCheck : ongoingPrecuationsList) {
                for (WebElement ongoingPrecuationsChk : ongoingPrecuations) {
                    if (ongoingPrecuationsChk.getAttribute("value").equalsIgnoreCase(ongoingPrecuationsCheck)) {
                        ongoingPrecuationsChk.click();

                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: If the line is skipped the condition in the `if` is false. Debug it, check if the values are really equal (including spaces).

Comment: use xpath like //tbody//input, this will give you array of checkbox input.

Comment: I am able to locate the webelement but cannot click on checkbox

Comment: Sorry my bad i didn't check question description. Please see answer below. Thanks

Comment: Can you provide additional info as 1) If you are attempting to click all the `<td>` (check box) elements? 2)If the `<table>` contains only these 3 `<td>` elements? 3) If number of `<td>` (check box) elements and number of elements in `List<String> ongoingPrecuationsList` are same? and 4) If number of `<td>` (check box) element and number of elements in `List<String> ongoingPrecuationsList` are different?

Answer (score 0):

Use xpath based on id of tbody like below.

```
//tbody[contains(@id,'tableBodyId')]//input
```

This will give you list of checkboxes. Then use

```
WebElement btn = driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath"));

btn.click();
```

Comment: i have mutiple tables with mutiple checkbox in the same webpage.so it cannot be located using xpath("//tbody[contains(@id,'tableBodyId')]");

Comment: Yes agreed, but id is unique for every tag so replace tableBodyId text with your id of tbody.

Comment: use xpath :- //table[contains(@id,'ContentPlaceHolder')]//input